# Silverstripe 3.1 table of multiple many_many relationships

Tags: silverstripe

I have a DataObject "Rectangle". It stands in a many_many relationship with "AttributeValue" (e.g. 10 inch). The DataObject "AttributeValue" stands also in a many_many relationship to "Attribute" (e.g. length (or width)). I want to create a table in the CMS on the page "Rectangle", which shows the AttributeValue and the related Attribute:

**Attribute   | Value**

length | 10 inch

width  | 20 inch

color  | red

Cause Attribute is not related to Rectangle, I don't know how to get the data in that table. The values for the table are generated with this code:

```
class Rectangle extends Page {
    private static $db = array(...);
    private static $many_many = array(
        'AttributeValue' => 'AttributeValue',
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
        $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            'AttributeValue'=>'Value'
        ));

        $attrField = new GridField(
            'AttributeValue',
            'AttributeValue',
            $this->AttributeValue(),
            $config
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attribute', $attrField);        
        return $fields;
    }
}
class AttributeValue extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('AttributeValue' => 'Varchar');
    private static $belongs_many_many = array('Rectangle' => 'Rectangle');
    private static $many_many   = array('Attribute' => 'Attribute');
}

class Attribute extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('Attribute' => 'Varchar');   
    private static $belongs_many_many = array('AttributeValue' => 'AttributeValue');
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have a `Rectangle` with some `AttributeValues` related to it (e.g. 10 inch, 20 inch, red), so in the database there's a table Rectangle_AttributeValue, which shows the relation. I also have the Object `Attribute` which is related to `AttributeValue` (table AttributeValue_Attribute), e.g. 10 inch -> length, or red -> color. So the whole "relation chain" looks like: Rectangle->AttributeValue->Attribute (Rectangle1 -> 10 inch -> length, or Rectangle1 -> red -> color). I hope I could make it more clear...

Comment: Shouldn't `AttributeValue` have a `$has_one` relationship with `AttributeType`? `AttributeValue` can't be both _length_ and _width_. `AttributeType` would have a `$has_many` relationship with `AttributeValue`, but not a many to many.

Comment: AttributeValue can be for both, example: 10 inch can be the value for length, and it can be also the value for width. (AttributeValue is an object, so I get a table, where the values shouldn't appear more than once.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for clarity you should probably pluralize your many_many declarations like:

```
private static $many_many   = array('AttributeTypes' => 'AttributeType');
```

and

```
private static $belongs_many_many = array('Rectangles' => 'Rectangle');
```

To answer your question "Cause AttributeType is not related to Rectangle, I don't know how to get the data in that table": You don't, and you're not supposed to. To get an attribute with certain types "in" the rectangle page, you shpuld first create an attribute with the associated types, and then add that to the Rectangle page. You could then access the types like:

```
foreach($this->AttributeValues() as $attribute) {
    echo "attribute: ".$attribute->AttributeValue."<br />";
    foreach($attribute->AttributeTypes() as $type) {
        echo "type: ".$type->AttributeType."<br />;
    }
}
```

But maybe you just want to show the types in the back end in the CMS, on the rectangle page. For that you could just add an extra, non existing field to the static $summary_fields in the rectangle object, e.g.

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    "yourfield" => "CMS Titel", //one line per field you want in the summary
    "AttributeValuesAndTypes" => "Attribute values and types"
);
```

You could then use the above code to do something like this in your rectangle class:

```
public function getAttributeValuesAndTypes() {
    $attributes = array();
    foreach($this->AttributeValues() as $attribute) {
        $types = array();
        foreach($attribute->AttributeTypes() as $type) {
            $types[] = $attribute->AttributeType;
        }
        $attributes[] = $attribute->AttributeValue." (".implode(",",$types).")";
    }
    return implode(",",$attributes);
}
```

This would add an extra column in your overview with "Atribute 1 (Type 1,Type 2), Attribute 2 (Type 2, Type 3) etc". As an added bonus, you can get rid of the extra getCMSFields stuff.

Note that this could get messy pretty soon when you have a lot of attributes per rectangle, and a lot of types per attribute.

Hope this helps. If not, please clarify your question a bit :-)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but unfortunately it doesn't help me.. I think, you've misunderstood my situation, to make it more clear I've edited my question

Comment: Nope, sorry. You are not making it more clear. Basicly, I do not know what you are trying to achieve. In your present setup, you can store everything in the DB as you wish, as there is a relation between rectangle and type, through attributevalue. You can not store Type in the Rectangle table, because type is something that belongs on the attributevalue table. So, in what table are you trying to store what, and - most importantly - for what reason?

Comment: Ok, I have three objects: Rectangle(box1), AttributeValue(10 inch, 20 inch, red), Attribute (length, width, color). All I want to do is to display the data in a simple Silverstripe gridfield in the CMS. I can create a gridfield with the related AttributeValues to the Rectangle, but I also want that the Attributes, which are related to the Values are displayed. I don't know the notation in "Silverstripe-language" to get the data of an indirectly related object (-> the Attribute)

Comment: But that is what I tried to do in the second half of my answer. It probably is copy-paste (but not tested), and will add an extra column to the summary grid field.

Comment: Could you tell me how many maximum attributes you are likely to have for one Rectangle?

Comment: @ninty9notout: hard to say... it can be 10 or 20

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I wouldn't recommend the approach that you are taking as you will have a `Attribute` record for every unique value that will get used; thus the setup will almost look like an EAV model. EAV models **ARE BAD**.

Having said that, it maybe the only approach for this. This is how I would structure it:

```
class Rectangle extends Page {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Attributes' => 'Attribute'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attributes', new GridField('Attributes', 'Attributes', $this->Attributes(), GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()));

        return $fields;
    }
}

class Attribute extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)', // You may want to make this an enum to limit what gets added 'Enum(array("Length", "Width", "Colour"))'
        'Value' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Pages' => 'Page'
    );

    static $summary_fields = array(
        'Title',
        'Value'
    );

    static $searchable_fields = array(
        'Title',
        'Value'
    );
}
```

There is no need for a third model here. The name and value gets stored as `Attribute` and that is attached to the page.

I use a structure almost identical to this to save attributes for products in my commerce module. Works like a charm.

Let me know what you think of this approach.

More on EAV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model